# If statement with comparison

Tags: clojure

I am trying to do a comparison to find the largest number in a list. I know I could just use the (max 1 2 4 3) but I'm trying to write the function myself. However, I'm not too sure where the error is. Whenever I run this, the maximum is always 2. Am I doing a comparison wrong somewhere or forget something?

```
(defn maxVal [list]
  (def maxValue 0)

  (doseq [x list]
    (println x maxValue)
    (if > x maxValue)
      (do (println x ">" maxValue)
          (def maxValue x)))
    (var-get #'maxValue))

(maxVal '(1 4 3 2))
```

Comment: Not your immediate problem, but as an aside -- `var`s aren't meant to be used this way, and abusing them has some nasty side effects (they aren't designed to be particularly fast/cheap to update, for example, so there are locks involved). Stick to `atom`s if you need something you can alter, or better, just use `loop`/`recur` for code (like this!) that can just rebind names and doesn't need to have mutable values at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code is evaluating `>` as a value, not invoking it as a function.

```
(if > x maxValue)
```

...evaluates to `x`, because the function `>` is neither `nil` nor false, and thus is truthy when evaluated as a boolean -- and `x` is in the "if true" position, just as `maxValue` is in the "else" position in this `if`. Consequently, the current indentation (while it reflects *intent* accurately) is a bit misleading; the `do` should be outside the `if`, since it takes place no matter what happened prior.

Presumably, what you instead want is:

```
(if (> x maxValue)
```